# How to create a route in Laravel based on user type?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-6, laravel-authorization

Based on a User model and table already created, what is the best practice to create a route based on user type?

Usertype is a model and table field.

Does Gates and/or Policies are the best practice?

Eg.: If an authenticated user is an admin user, it can access some views, if the user is a non-admin, it can access other views.

There are many links on the internet, but I can not find "the one".

Comment: This kind of question is not a good fit for Stackoverflow, as it is a little too broad, and opinionated (ie should you use policies, guards, middleware or something else). Do some more research, attempt to implement one of the solutions (that *you* find fits your needs), and if you have a specific issue, then you can ask a question.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the different views have many elements in common, maybe it would be a good idea to create a view as the template, and then other views extending that template, setting their different parts as blade sections.

```
{{-- Template --}}
<span>The view</span>
<div>
   @yield('content')
</div>
```

```
{{-- One of the views --}}
@extends('template')
@section('content')
   <span>Specific content</span>
@endsection
```

---

If the content presented in each view is completely different, it might be a good idea to have one controller method for each one. Then, for the one route use a closure to decide which controller method gets called depending on the criteria you need.

```php
Route::get('/products/{product}', function (Product $product) {
    $method = Gate::allows('view_details', $product) ? 'viewDetails' : 'viewGeneralInfo';
    return app('ProductController')
        ->callAction($method, ['product' => $product]);
});
```